# git submodule not updating to parent branch

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have the following in my `.gitmodules`:

```
[submodule "django"]
    path = django
    url = git@gitlab.******.com:path/to/django.git
    branch = .
```

This file is identical in my `master` and `uat` branches.

Regarding the branch, from the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitmodules)

> A special value of . is used to indicate that the name of the branch
> in the submodule should be the same name as the current branch in the
> current repository.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
git checkout master && git submodule sync && git submodule update && git submodule status
```

Which gives me:

```
f6d808827aca47984d495e0fe2403dd41f042e40 django (heads/master)
```

I switch the parent to `uat` branch:

```
git checkout uat && git submodule sync && git submodule update && git submodule status
```

This outputs the exact same ref:

```
f6d808827aca47984d495e0fe2403dd41f042e40 django (heads/master)
```

I expect it to be pointing at a commit on the `uat` branch.

Why isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Ah. I think I needed to run `git submodule update` with the `--remote` flag. Otherwise it tries to update the submodule using whatever commit the parent last pointed it at. "Remote" tells it to.... update the submodule using the submodule's own commit history? Or something? From the docs:

> Instead of using the superproject’s recorded SHA-1 to update the
> submodule, use the status of the submodule’s remote-tracking branch.